Profile metadata doesn't contains Layout Information when fetched using Salesforce CLI
I am trying to create a bash script which will backup my org's data daily. For that I thought salesforce cli is the best option as it can be used in my script. But after retrieving data it turns out Profile data is limited when fetched using cli (I tried sfdx and sf scripts both).
But If I retrieve from VS code using Salesforce Extension Pack i am getting layout information as well as record type information in profiles.
Is there a way I can get layout and recordtype information in profile using salesforce cli or please suggest any other method to achieve this.
Commands I am using

sf project retrieve start --metadata Profile
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Profile


If you want more information together with your profile, then you have to retrieve those metadata(s) together with Profile. Example:
sf project retrieve start --metadata Profile RecordType

You need to retrieve the profile as part of a package that includes those items.  profiles by themselves don't include all metadata related to the profile

@prem22  A very big thanks to you guys. I have tested this and it is working as I was expecting it to work.
